# Eastic search and searching comma seperated values in a field

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a table with generally normal columns which can be searched on in the normal way, however we have an edge case called "color"

```
    "colors": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "norms": false,
        "fields": {
            "lowercase": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "businesskey_analyzer_lowercase",
                "search_analyzer": "businesskey_analyzer_lowercase"
            }
        }
    },
```

This column contain any number of comma seperated "colors" for example : "red, blue, green, black".

We want to search on this column but only on specific values like "red" or "green"

What we do not want is tokens within the string making it selectable like so : "ed, bl" or "e, g".

Is this something that can somehow be customized in elastic?

Comment: Why not simply splitting on commas and storing an array of separate tokens?

Comment: how is that done?

Comment: Either on the client side when building your documents, or at indexing time using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with [`split` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/split-processor.html)

Comment: I think adding a pattern tokenizer is the proper way to handle this, here is an example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html#_example_configuration_10